# How to use thumbnail view in yii2

Tags: gridview, replace, yii2

How to replace a gridview to thumbnail view , as in the picture

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5gySyqZ4GGoa2ktOURFT21veFk

Help me please
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use ListView instead of Gridview, you can design everything you need.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html#listview

You can define a itemView with a view of your choice and do any kind of design to it. Pagination will work automatically.

Comment: how to create layout or pager in listview? can you give me an example of coding itemview with layout or pager? thanks

Comment: the first 2 code boxes from my link give you an example.